# How to create subplots of subplots with custom plotting function using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use the following code to create subplots of subplots. The plotting function is:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    for i, f in enumerate(freq_bins, start=1):
        subj_file = base_dir + subject + '_' + f + '.txt'
        if os.path.exists(subj_file):
            freq_mat = np.loadtxt(subj_file, delimiter=',')
        else:
            freq_mat = np.zeros((46,46))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,i)
        ax.set_title("{0}".format(f))
        ax.spy(freq_mat, markersize=1, color='black')
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_xticks([])
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.suptitle("{0}".format(subject), fontsize=16)
```

And the code that I am trying to use to loop through this function is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
for i, s in enumerate(all_subjects, start=1):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,4,i)
    ax = plot_freq_bin_mats(s, freq_bins)
    plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

The function works as all plots are able to be shown but when I attempt to save the figure, I get a blank plot that is in the layout of the plotting function. A blank plot is shown preceding the other plots. I am using jupyter notebook. Why am I getting the blank figure and why are the plots not added to the figure and able to be saved?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but can you comment the line ```plt.tight_layout()``` and see what happens?

Comment: Tried that previously and didn’t work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to do is not possible. Instead please read on [SubplotSpec](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#gridspec-using-subplotspec)

Comment: This was very helpful! However, I am still having trouble adding a title to the subplot specs. Is there a way to do this?